# XSD is not generated for Enum Type using JAXB schemagen in Java8

Tags: java, java-8, enums, xsd, jaxb

I have a simple enum class like

```
public enum TestEnum{
ONE("one"),
TWO("two"),
THREE("three");
}
```

Now want to generate xsd from this enum type using jaxb on JDK8. I am using jaxb-xjc 2.2.6 and jaxb-impl 2.2.6 version. But the schema is not generated.

Iam using ant build to generate the schema.

I have tried with @xmlType @xmlEnum @xmlEnumValue etc annotations in the enum as well.

Please help to provide a solution .

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?